# Unable to derive typeclass instance for Coproduct using shapeless in scala 2.11.8

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

I have a generic XML writer like below (minimal code to reproduce the issue):

```
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless._

import scala.language.{implicitConversions, postfixOps}
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, Text, XML}


trait XmlLabelledWrites[T] {
  def write(value: T): NodeSeq
}

object XmlLabelledWrites {
  def apply[T](implicit ev: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[T]]): XmlLabelledWrites[T] = ev.value

  implicit def deriveHCons[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList]
  (implicit
   key: Witness.Aux[K],
   xfh: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[V]],
   xft: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[T]]
  ): XmlLabelledWrites[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = ???

  implicit def deriveHNil: XmlLabelledWrites[HNil] = ???

  implicit def deriveInstance[F, G]
  (implicit
   gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[F, G],
   lx: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[G]]
  ): XmlLabelledWrites[F] =
    new XmlLabelledWrites[F] {
      override def write(value: F): NodeSeq = ???
    }

  implicit def deriveCNil: XmlLabelledWrites[CNil] = ???

  implicit def deriveCCons[K <: Symbol, V, T <: Coproduct]
  (implicit
   key: Witness.Aux[K],
   scv: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[V]],
   sct: Lazy[XmlLabelledWrites[T]]
  ): XmlLabelledWrites[FieldType[K, V] :+: T] =
    new XmlLabelledWrites[FieldType[K, V] :+: T] {
      override def write(value: FieldType[K, V] :+: T): NodeSeq = ???
    }
}
```

With the above code, I can do the following:

```
object WriterApp extends App {
  import Data._

  implicitly[XmlLabelledWrites[Opt]]

}

object Data {
  sealed trait Opt

  case class StrOpt() extends Opt
  case class IntOpt() extends Opt

}
```

But the code won't compile with the following error

> could not find implicit value for parameter e: XmlLabelledWrites[Data.Opt]

Now if I change the scala version to `2.12.9` or place `object Data` above `WriterApp` in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nFk6RUabTV63GMVRb3Xmvw), the code will compile. I guess this is a bug that was fixed unless I am missing something.

Unfortunately, I am stuck with `2.11.8` for this project, and placing all the ADTs in the same file is also not possible. Is there a workaround or fix?

[scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/nFk6RUabTV63GMVRb3Xmvw).

Comment: Can you check if using `2.11.12` solves the issue?

Comment: The issue remains with `2.11.12`.